# Adding a class to a div when over a certain area / section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change my navigation colour when it is over a dark header. I have managed to do this, but the page does not load in that state.

You can see it here, the navigation top left changes from white to black in respect of if it is over the dark top bar header or not.

http://www.pagedev.co.uk/clients/lotuslaser/

Here is my Jquery.

```
<script>
  var header = $('#nav_list'),
    blueSection = $('.full-header'),
    // Calculate when to change the color.
    offset = blueSection.offset().top + blueSection.height() - header.height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    // Remove Class "dark" after scrolling over the dark section
    if (scroll >= offset) {
      header.removeClass('white-nav');
    } else {
      header.addClass('white-nav');
    }

    // Remove Class "no-shadows" whenever not on the top of the page.
    if (scroll >= 1) {
      header.removeClass('no-shadow');
    } else {
      header.addClass('no-shadow');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Any help would be great!

Another questions on the same matter... how do I also add another container into the mix, so that it can also change to white when it rolls over the black strip at the base of the page.

Thank you in advance.

Lee

Comment: Hi! To make it easier for people to help you, please make the runnable example **here, on-site**, not offsite, not least because your question must be fully self-contained here on-site (in the above, you haven't shown any of your HTML structure, for instance). You can update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, making it runnable using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: By far, the best way to do this is not to do it with JavaScript at all. Instead, use [the `:hover` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

Comment: Use `$.on` with multiple events: `$(window).on('scroll load', function(){` so your code runs on both events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best way is to use [**Midnight.js**](http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/) Plugin